# yii2: fetch ObjectID of mongoDB using yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to fetch ObjectID from mongodb but i did not get the same id.
Look my below code.

```
 $query->select([])
 ->from('firmadmin')
 ->where(['userName' => $user]);


 if($rows!=null)
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {

                $response['uid'] = $row['_id'];

        }
    }
```

When i check my response it shows `'sacOUbxUR.b7E'`. But this is not my actual id.
In Mongodb my actual id is "_id" : `ObjectId("55a48f00d88488d50ea7c07d")`
I want my actual id `55a48f00d88488d50ea7c07d`.
can you tell how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `select([])` call and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

change `$row['_id'];` with `(string)$row['_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = new Query();
    $query->select(['_id'])
            ->from('firmadmin');
    $rows = $query->all();
    $data = [];
    foreach ($rows as $value) {
        $data['uid'] = (string)$value['_id'];
    }
    return $data;
```